# barcode scanner in a disabled state after reboot

Tags: serial

My barcode scanner is configured as a USB serial device.  it shows up as ACM0 I believe.  It works fine with my python program.  THen after a hard reboot, the scanner seems to be in a different state, and will no longer pass barcodes to the program.

The program no longer sees the scanner as ACM0.  Once it detects it on ACM0, all is good.   If I unplug the scanner and re-plug....it is OK, and recognized.   But I cannot have a system that doesnt work after a power failure.

The scanner has status lights, and if I unplug it and plug it back in, the lights indicate a good state, and it beeps when reading a code.   After the hard system reboot, it seems that the Pi powers up....does something to the scanner, and puts it in a state where it no longer even beeps to read a barcode.   I have to unplug it and plug it back in.  What is happening please????

Comment: `What is happening?` cannot be answered with the limited info that you provided... only `what could be happening?` can be answered ... check to see if the scanner configures itself as a USB keyboard

Comment: Is it possible to power down the scanner then when reboot is finished restart it? That will give linux time to settle down before inumeriating the USB ports.